# How can the Case History fields present in Case Lifecycle report type be retrieved with SOQLs?

Tags: soql, reporting, case, fields

In the standard report type Case Lifecycle the following fields of Case History object can be retrieved even if not present in the object itself:

- Case History Owner
- Case History Status
- Case History Last Modified By
- Case History Last Modified Date
- Business Hours Duration

There is a way to retrieve them through SOQLs or other means different than reports?

Comment: I am looking for this answer to. What I have found is that the following query gets some of this data but not all (mainly, I havent figured out how to get Duration)

select *
from case c 
join casehistory ch on c.id = ch.caseid 
left join account a on c.accountid = a.id 
left join contact co on c.contactid = co.id 
left join user cho on ch.createdbyid = cho.id

But there are some nuances. Casehistory sometimes gets double records (SF-ID + Name). Some of the records, are not part of lifecycle. Struggling to figure out the logic being used.